# How to link Tensorflow build from source to a C++ project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, include, bazel

I've been trying to run Tensorflow on C++ for a while now unsuccessfully.
What I've done so far is:

- Clone Tensorflow from Github
- Download and install Bazel to build from Source
- successfully build Tensorflow as follows:

[image]

As you can See, I have [ bazel-bin, bazel-out, bazel-tensorflow & bazel-testlogs] After building

Right now I'm trying to import Tensorflow but i'm not sure exactly what to do.

I've tried adding

- \tensorflow\bazel-bin\tensorflow
- \tensorflow\bazel-tensorflow\external\eigen_archive

to the project properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Libraries and still I have errors:

[image]

Comment: As you can guess from the header name, ``c_api.h`` provides **C** interface, not C++ one. For **C++** classes and functions you need to include other headers. E.g. ``tensorflow::Tensor`` class is [declared](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor) in the header ``tensor.h``.

Comment: Note also, that Stack Overflow discourages usage of *image* for show the code. Instead, provide the code as a **text**. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for the answer. What folder should I use to include all the necessary .h files? Bazel-bin, Bazel-out or Bazel-tensorlfow?

Comment: Just find which folder contains the file `tensor.h` and use this folder as include one.